# Div content change size depending on navigator

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[image: The image from left to right is safari,chrome and firefox]

You can see that size varies from one navigator to another

**Code to open pop :**

```
self.chatWindow = window.open('/chat', 'winname', "directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,width=350,height=600");
```

Here is the HTML code of the page i use angular 2 in the front end

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper1">
        // more html code
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
 .wrapper {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper1{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 288px;
  width: 288px;
  max-height: 480px;
  maheight: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I would like all pop to have the same size that the safari one have

Comment: What's your `container` class doing? Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes the app must have a fixed size like the size 288x480